# PG alternative to grouping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

In development on sqlite this works a charm:

```
@human = Human.joins(:human_logins).group("human_logins.human_id").order("count(human_logins.human_id) ASC")
```

Though, in production on Heroku and using PG, it crashes and I get the following error:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "humans.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Guessing it's just a compatibility problem, any insight on how I can alter this so that it works nicely in production would be awesome.

Comment: Yes @muistooshort, I'm a beginner if I'm honest and i'm trying to comprehend how I would adapt the posted fixes to my scenario :(

Comment: @muistooshort Will migrate soon. I'm trying to simply count by association. Human is my model, it has_many human_logins and I want to  order humans by the count of their human_logins association